# Prevent IntelliJ from automatically switching run/debug configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

In intelliJ I would like to keep a certain run configuration as default. I have a gradle project, and when I run gradle tasks it switches the active run configuration to that task.

My preference is to keep my application server run configuration as default and prevent auto switching. I only want intelliJ to switch the active run configuration if I do it manually.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option at the moment.

You can use [Run Configuration as Action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action) plug-in as a workaround. Create an action for your run configuration and put it on the toolbar or assign a keyboard shortcut. This way you can always run this specific run configuration with a single click/hotkey no matter which one is selected in the dropdown.

See also the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968) and the linked issues.